# how can I get specific contents under the "script" tag

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm scraping the H&M webpage using beautiful soup and am trying to convert the javascript into a string and then extract the clothing size information from it. I think first I need to get the string, then I should split the string and extract the part I'm looking for, and finally I can use `json.load()` to convert the string into a dictionary, so that I can get values from that dictionary. But I ran into the problem when I try to extract the part from the lengthy and messy string. Also, since the script has blended `''` and `""`, I cannot directly load them using `json.load()` as well. Can anyone help me figure out how to extract the part that I'm looking for?

The webpage I'm scraping is: https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.0624684003.html.

This is how I find the script tag and convert it into a sting:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.90 Safari/537.36'
url='https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.0931364012.html'
headers =   {'accept':'*/*',"user-agent":user_agent}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
script = page.find('div', class_="product parbase").find('script').string 

# This is how I find the first level of dictionary:
firstlevel_dict = script.split('productArticleDetails = ')[1]

# in the next step, I hope to convert the above string-like dictionary into a real dictionary, and then find the all displayed sizes for this t-shirt
```

I attached a screenshot showing how the HTML looks like in the following, contents in the red box are what I'm looking for. In the end, I hope to get a list of sizes which looks like `['S','M','L','XL','XXL','3XL']`.
[image]

PS: I'm also open to other methods that can potentially find the size of H&M clothes. Thanks!

PS_plus: I don't wish to use Selenium in this case since I have thousands of products to scrape. Selenium will be too way time inefficient to get the information I want.

Comment: Please upload VALID python code into the post. The current code is not valid

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I forgot to add user agent

Comment: Python has [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). At a glance, it looks like the object format is close enough to python's list and object formats that it may parse correctly. Once you can extract just the value of `productArticleDetails`, you may be able to run it through `eval()` and get a python data structure.

Answer (score 1):

continuing from where you left off the string that you were getting wasn't completely JSON data formatting the text to have

```
# This is how I find the first level of dictionary:
firstlevel_dict = script.split('productArticleDetails = ')[1]
dictionary_to_get = firstlevel_dict[:firstlevel_dict.rfind(';')] # remove ';' at the end of the string to make it part of a dictionary

dictionary_to_get = dictionary_to_get.replace('\'', '"') # first error -- the text is formatted with single quotes where json needs double
dictionary_to_get = dictionary_to_get.replace('isDesktop ?', '"isDesktop ?",') # second error this word is part of a strange double value (dictionary with a dictionary) didn't know how you would have liked it to format, so did a simple solution to load the dictionary

print(json.loads(dictionary_to_get))
```

Now you are able to traverse the dictionary to get your info which could look like:

```
for k,v in json_dictionary.items():
    try:
        int(k)
    except:
        continue
    #print(v['sizes']) # print the size dictionary totally (outside your highlight)
    for item in v['sizes']:
        print(item['name']) # get just the name
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is so cool!

Comment: But a follow-up question, how did you figure out the `isDesktop ?` is not recognized by python? Hope I can also identify it next time when I run into a similar question

Comment: @wydncwymsjgcs after changing the single to double it wasn't working. I then loaded the response that I had changed into https://jsonformatter.org/ to see what was not formatted properly which was that element (the first error that I saw) when I tried to validate the json

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Andrew!

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you copy and paste the string into that website? But why when I pasted it, the website always reminds me \r\n UNDEFINED or something like that. May I know the procedure of how you check the string? Thank you!

Comment: after the line with the comment first error, I printed(dictionary_to_get) and copied that, and placed it into the site. The site then gave me an error (when I clicked validate) which was on line 68 (which is the first time that string is mentioned).  Let me know if this is a good explanation. If not we can move this to the python chatroom for a longer discussion. (and step by step)

Comment: Ohhh I got it! I add a print() to display the result, then there is no stuff like "\n\r" occurs! Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewRyan `? :` is javascript for an inline `if`/`then`/`else` ([conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)). Altering it the way you do (re: `isDesktop`) messes up the key:value association.

Comment: @Ouroborus it changes the data slightly although still accessible it was not part of the data that OP needed